# Why 'perf' needs to match the exact running Linux kernel version?

Tags: linux, kernel, perf

If you try to run a random `perf` binary that does not match your currently running Linux kernel, it says:

```
$ perf
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.13.0-45
```

Of course, if I get the `perf` for this version, it works.

Looking at some popular resources like [Linux perf Examples](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) and the [Perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) I couldn't find the answer for this specific question: *why `perf` strictly needs to be in the same version as the kernel?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perf` and the kernel are tied fairly closely together, in fact `perf` is part of the kernel source code. At heart you should think of it as a kernel-specific tool; but packaging practice and requirements in Linux distributions means users end up thinking of it as a “standard” tool.

There is no special `perf`-private interface between `perf` and the kernel, so the `perf`-supporting parts of the kernel have to follow the usual userspace-facing rules — *i.e.* maintain backward-compatibility; so in theory, it would be possible to run an older version of `perf` with a newer kernel, since the newer kernel is supposed to support whatever interface the older version of `perf` uses to communicate with it. However, in practice it turns out that if you need to use `perf` to investigate performance of a workload on a given kernel, you also need to be able to investigate all the performance-affecting features of that particular kernel; an older version of `perf` can’t support features which were added after it was released, so you would typically end up needing the matching version of `perf` anyway. As a result of all this, the pragmatic option is to require a version of `perf` matching the running kernel.

Depending on your distribution’s packaging choices, `perf` may be a front-end which checks for an implementation of `perf` matching your running kernel, and fails if it can’t find one; or it may be some version of `perf` itself. I haven’t tested going back too far, but current versions of `perf` work fine on older kernels, for example `perf` 5.6.14 and 5.7.7 work fine with a 4.19 kernel.

Comment: What about newer perf with older kernel? Why we just cant have latest version of perf with any version of kernel?

Comment: @catpnosis that does work now, at least I can run `perf` 5.7 on a 4.19 kernel.