# linux-tools-common when on a newer kernel version

Tags: linux-mint, apt, perf

I'm currently running kernel 5.16.15-051615-generic - I've landed on it while diagnosing and trying to fix an audio issue. Everything works great now so I'm reluctant to go back to 5.4.0

I'd like to install and use perf, but the linux-tools-common package in apt shows version 5.4.0-107.121.

I've read that you need to use a version of the package compiled for your kernel version, and haven't found anything for 5.16. I guess that's to be expected - but how can I get a version for my kernel? Is there some in-development unofficial repository that has them? Or am I out of luck?

If it helps, I used Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer to install the new kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [the Ubuntu mainline kernel builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) don’t publish packages for the kernel-related tools (`perf` etc.).

You can try using the packaged versions of the tools; most of their functionality should work fine with a newer kernel (see [Why 'perf' needs to match the exact running Linux kernel version?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462981/86440)). You can also build them yourself, using [the source tree matching your kernel package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Kernel_source_code_trees).

A better long-term solution would be to report your issues to the Linux Mint bug tracker, with details of the kernel which fixed them; that way the relevant fixes might get backported to the distribution kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was unable to run the 5.4.0 perf as it would only emit a warning about there not being any perf for 5.16.15 (I assume then that the kernel I downloaded was not built with perf included?) and not allow anything else. I installed 5.4.0-107 which is newer than the 5.4.0 I was running at first. Audio seems ok with this version too at least for now and I can run perf now. Building from source is a bit out of my comfort zone right now :(